# display strangely in list paging index

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm developing a web site using list paging, in the view I wrote like this:

```
@using PagedList;
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@model Bank2.Models.ViewModel.PaymentView
...
<table>
   @Html.PagedListPager( Model.plist , page => Url.Action("Payment", new { page }) )
   ...      
</table>
```

but it looks like: 
[image]

Can anybody tell what's wrong in my code? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well maybe the `Html.PagedListPager` is generating some `<ul>`/`<li>` tags. It is quite unclear from your question where is this helper coming from (because there's no such thing in ASP.NET MVC) but you could always use CSS to style them appropriately.

For example something along the lines of the following might actually cut the mustard:

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
}

li {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for! thank you for making stackoverflow a better place! I really appreciated and enjoyed your answer, I used the same code but first one looks just perfect, do you have any ideas? maybe the second time .NET performed differently?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. But Just dragging and dropping the PagedList CSS reference solved the problem.
like this

```
<link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Plus you can use some built-in styles by passing values the third parameter PagedListRenderOptions in html.PagedListPager() function call.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing the CSS styles associated with the paging elements.

You probably want to add a "`float:left`" for the `<li>` elements.

Comment: It's always perfect to see your answer in the next morning, I enjoyed that, thank you for helping me!@Queti Mporta

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as Queti and Dmitri have both put it, I believe you just need to add a little CSS styling, most likely in the form of floats.

If you still aren't happy with your paging try following along with [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application). Great tutorial on paging.

Answer (score 0):

You can drag and drop the PagedList.css file into your .cshtml razor view, this will display the pager control the way you are looking for